# onclick to display images from dB using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display images from database when using onclick button (passing variable) .

```
 <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="<?= 
base_url().'users/viewimage'.$record->userId; 
?>" title="Login history"><i class="fa fa- 
 history"></i></a> |
```

controller

```
function viewimage(){
    $data = array();

    $this->load->model('upload_images');

    $data['uploaded_images'] = $this->upload_images->get_images();


    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

model

```
function get_images(){
    $this->db->from('uploaded_images');
    $this->db->order_by('date_uploaded', 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();        

}
```

How to i get it? suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

in your view update

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="<?= 
base_url().'users/viewimage/'.$record->userId; 
?>" title="Login history"><i class="fa fa- 
 history"></i></a> |
```

in controller

```
function viewimage($userId){
    $data = array();
    $this->load->model('upload_images');
    $data['uploaded_images'] = $this->upload_images->get_images($userId);
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

in model

```
function get_images($userId){
    $this->db->from('uploaded_images');
    $this->db->where("userId = $userId");
    $this->db->order_by('date_uploaded', 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();        
}
```